# Image Captions on Hover

Tags: html, css, captions

I'm trying to implement a feature for my website where hovering over an image shows its caption over the bottom of the image. Any tips on how to do this?
I was trying to do it, but something in the css template I'm using was interfering.

Here are the images I want to put captions for

```
<section class="5grid is-gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="4u"> <a href="matthewpiatetsky.com/MicroChess.html" class="image image-full"><img src="images/1a.jpg" alt=""></a>

        </div>
        <div class="4u"> <a href="matthewpiatetsky.com/ClusteringDistance.html" class="image image-full"><img src="images/2a.jpg" alt=""></a>

        </div>
        <div class="4u"> <a href="matthewpiatetsky.com/FourInARow.html" class="image image-full"><img src="images/3a.jpg" alt=""></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="4u"> <a href="matthewpiatetsky.com/Fidelity.html" class="image image-full"><img src="images/4a.jpg" alt=""></a>

        </div>
        <div class="4u"> <a href="matthewpiatetsky.com/Concordance.html" class="image image-full"><img src="images/5a.jpg" alt=""></a>

        </div>
        <div class="4u"> <a href="matthewpiatetsky.com/PhotoShare.html" class="image image-full"><img src="images/6a.png" alt=""></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Note: I tried to use these, not exactly sure what I was doing wrong.
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/

Comment: Does it have any CSS code?

Comment: yup here it is. 
http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/css/style.css

Comment: Should there not be an `:hover` pseudo class afecting `div.4u a`? Maybe I haven't understand you. :-/

Comment: well there should be i'm just not sure how to make it display a caption over image if i hover over

Comment: also my apologies i gave you wrong css file. most of the stuff for the 5grid is in here
http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/css/5grid/core.css

Comment: everything you want is here, learn and adjust http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-image-captions/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code to achieve this would be something like this:

```css
a {
  position: relative
}

a span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}

a:hover span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  <span>caption</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If JavaScript+jQuery is acceptable, try jQuery TipTip plugin: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

> TipTip uses the title attribute just like the native browser tooltip does. However, the title will be copied and then removed from the element when using TipTip so that the browser tooltip will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use also CSS `attr()`.

```
a {
  position: relative;
}

a:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Could also use another attribute, like `alt`.